# How do I set my rails app up so that I can click a letter and see only the entries starting with that letter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, alphabetical-sort

My rails app basically displays a dictionary of sorts, which is stored in a database. I've set up a basic rails app with scaffold to display this on a webpage, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to set this next bit up. Basically I want a row of the 26 alphabetical letters, and when you click on a letter (say 'A'), I only want to see the dictionary entries of that letter.

My index.html.erb file:

```
<% for char in 'A'..'Z' %>
<%= link_to( "#{char}", "/words/lettersearch", :id => "#{char}") %>
<% end %>
```

my words_controller.rb file method for doing this:

```
def lettersearch
    @word = Word.find(:all, :conditions => ["word LIKE ?", "#{params[:word]}%"])
end
```

It then outputs the @word to another page.

My problem is that it just outputs the entire dictionary again, no matter what letter I click on the index page. I know it's to do with the routing, as it never seems to actually run the 'lettersearch' method - it's always trying to run through the 'Show' method that's defined by default earlier in the controller.

Anyone able to give me a quick hand with how to route this thing through? I'm pretty new to rails and I don't understand the workings of link_to very well at all.

routes.rb:

```
Dictionary::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :words do

  post 'search', :on => :collection
  post 'lettersearch', :on => :collection
  end

#Rest of routes.rb still commented apart from
   match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing in a param called `:id` but in your controller you use a param called `:word`

Also, update your code to use newer syntax

```
World.where(["word like ?", "#{params[:id]}%"])
```

And your view code can be cleaned as well

```
<% for char in 'A'..'Z' %>
  <%= link_to char, "/words/lettersearch", :id => char %>
<% end %>
```

Your routes file only has a POST route to letter search, but a link_to is a GET request.  So whats happening is the GET request is hitting `/words/:id` via GET which is the show action by default, and the `params[:id]` inside that request will be "lettersearch"

Comment: Cheers for the help. But it is still routing to the

    "def show" default
   
method in the controller, and not the lettersearch method that I've declared myself later in the file.

Comment: Stuck it up in the main post

Comment: Cheers man, you made me rethink what I was doing, and I got it to work shortly after. Thanks!

Comment: Cool. Glad to hear it.  Maybe accept the answer to close out the thread

Answer (score 0):

You could run the search in your index. I think that might be what you want to do. In your index controller you could put:

```
@orders = Order.lettersearch(params[:word])
```

and then in your model:

```
def lettersearch(word)

    if lettersearch
       @word = Word.find(:all, :conditions => ["word LIKE ?", "#{word}%"])
    else
       all
    end
end
```